# How can I use a 5200 mAh Li-Po battery to power multiple things?

Tags: power-electronics, raspberry-pi, lipo, hobbyist, autonomous

I'm building an autonomous car and have a 7.4V 5200mAh 2S Li-Po battery that needs to power the following components:

- Brushless DC Motor (Through ESC)
- Raspberry Pi 4
- Servo motor
- Arduino Uno
- Another smaller servo

I have bought these [DC-DC converters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MQGMOKI) for the purpose of dropping down the voltage to the respective components. Since the Li-Po battery has only one EC-5 power supply cable, I'm not able to figure out what I can use to connect all these electronics in parallel to the battery (Or is it even safe to do so!). I new to electronics and would appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: A master fuse and suitably rated fuses on sub circuits may be wise.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe for sure, just be careful not to short anything, Li-Po can output dozens or even hundreds of amps - that might cause fire hazard. Best idea that comes to my mind is to use some kind of power distribution board that are used e.g. in drones. That will make a couple of +/- pairs that will allow you to distribute it over your device. Here's is picture how it might look like.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding, LMatt! I have a follow up question. The power distribution board in the picture seems to be just a parallel connecting circuit. Would I be able to just connect all the positive terminals on the electronics to the positive of the battery and all the grounds to the negative of the battery? I'm fine with all of them getting the same voltage of 7.4V since I'll drop it down to my needs later on in the circuits.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine, as long as you are careful to avoid shorting battery.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solder multiple cables together to a home-made wiring harness. Use shrink tube or just electrical tape to insulate the soldered joints from each other. See 3-way splice here: https://learn.adafruit.com/make-it-glow-how-to-solder-neopixels-a-beginners-guide/splicing-wires
[image]

Or you can solder and cut perf board to make your own power distribution board similar to LMatt's answer:

[image: perf board]